# Как деэкранировать строку в c#

Tags: c#

На вход поступает строка вида : "\\t", которая экранируется как "\t"...
Соответственно необходимо преобразовать слэш + символ (не обязательно t) в спецсимвол, как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте этот метод:

[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=netframework-4.7.2)